# What does a -4 above the stave mean?

Tags: notation

I've recently encountered a `-4` above the stave in both vocal and instrumental jazz pieces. None of the students nor our director know what to do with it, what does it mean? Here are two examples:

**Wave - By Antonio Carlos Jobim - Arr. Paris Rutherford**
[image: Wave - Jobim - Arr. Rutherford]

**Birdland - By Joe Zawinul - Arr. Victor Lopez**
[image: Birdland - Zawinul - Arr. Lopez]

Comment: Possibly give us a larger peek at the dots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an indication of when to end the pitch. (And since this is jazz, it very well may be requesting a tongue stop.)

In other words, both of these pitches should end immediately on beat 4, even though the latter example appears as if the pitch should continue for one extra eighth note.

Comment: Would it be as good to write just the dotted minim and then a crotchet rest? Good players should be able to read and play it correctly. Maybe with a phrase line.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not sure of the rationale for the (relatively common) practice of tying held pitches to unnecessary eighth notes.

Comment: Why do they use the “one extra eighth note” if it is not sounded? — Sorry I see you don’t know either; perhaps worth a question in its own right!

Comment: That's what I mean; I have no idea! I've never encountered a decent answer to that question.

Comment: @PJTraill: If the doted half were followed by a quarter note, then on many instruments it would be necessary to end the note a moment *before* the start of the fourth beat.  In some cases, it would be helpful for a player to end a note just before the next beat even if what follows is a rest (especially the note should end the same time as notes performed by other performers who have a note following).

Comment: I've seen this odd distinction occasionally in choral music. Some English music in particular will tie a long note to the following eighth note in order to indicate that **this** is the beat where the closing consonant goes.

Comment: Do you know of any reference (book, web) which documents this notation?